Report Message - Outlook Add-In opens Browser and doesn't work correctly
I'm trying to use the "Report Message" Outlook Add-In which I think is MSFT developed to report a "Phishing" e-mail but it's opening the Edge browser to the following URL and not behaving correctly.
https://ipagave.azurewebsites.net/ReportMessage/FunctionFile.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$en-US$$$$16&_sm_au_=##RANDOMSTRING##
Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-office-365/submissions-outlook-report-messages?view=o365-worldwide#use-the-report-message-and-report-phishing-add-ins-in-outlook

I'm currently using Outlook Desktop Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20542) 64-bit
I have some experience writing Office Add-Ins so I recognize the URL but I know its not supposed to be opening in the browser and it's not deleting the e-mail and I get a never ending "Report Message is working on your Phishing request" and a prompt if I try to close Outlook that its still trying.
Note: It works in the "New" Outlook and Online Outlook


This isn't a developer problem, so I have to vote to close it, but I will pass on your experience to the right people. In the meantime, in Outlook open the Help tab, select Feedback, and then select Report a problem.

@RickKirkham, "Report a problem" is not an option, only "I like something", "I don't like something" and "I have a suggestion"....

We have different versions of Outlook, apparently. Use the "I don't like something" option.
